# Define a class that new a function in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

I want to use the 'class' syntax to create a class, and when it news an instance, the instance can be directly used as a Function.

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@bar) ->
  baz: ->
    console.log 'baz'
  ...

f = new Foo 'bar'
f() # runs () -> console.log @bar
f.baz() # 'baz'
```

Here is a [JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897218) but I cannot reproduce it in CoffeeScript using class syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can write a Coffeescript class which compiles to that Javascript (or something close).  The Coffeescript `class` insists on 2 things:

It ends the class body with `return AwesomeObject;`

If I put a `return bar` in the class body, it objects with `error: Class bodies cannot contain pure statements`.

The linked Javascript model is:

```
var AwesomeObject = (function() {
    var AwesomeObject = function() {...};
    ...
    return function() {
      var o = new AwesomeObject();
      ...};
})();
```

It defines an `AwesomeObject` constructor internally, but returns a different function.  This is clearer if the internal name is changed to `AwesomeObject1`.  It functions the same, but there is no way of accessing `AwesomeObject1` directly.

Also `AwesomeObject()` and `new AwesomeObject()` return the same thing.

```
{ [Function]
  whatstuff: 'really awesome',
  doStuff: [Function] }
```

The compiled Coffeescript (for `class AwesomeObject...`) instead is:

```
AwesomeObject = (function() {
  function AwesomeObject() {...}
  ...
  return AwesomeObject;
})();
```

P.S.
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/861
Coffeescript issue discussion on `new Foo()` versus `Foo()` syntax.  Consensus seems to be that while `new-less` calls are allowed in Javascript for objects like `Date`, it isn't encouraged for user defined classes.  This is interesting, though not really relevant to the question here.

Comment: The linked pattern is more complex that it is necessary. You can easily write a coffeescript class that does similar things with the same results, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@bar) ->
    return => console.log @bar

f = new Foo 'bar'
f()
```

Comment: This is what I've tried. The constructor returns a function, but it's not a formal constructor works. The returned function contains no methods in the class definition but a bare function. I edit my question and add a method in the class, please try that again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@bar) ->
    f = -> console.log bar
    for v, k of @
      f[v] = k
    return f
  baz: ->
    console.log 'baz'

f = new Foo 'bar'
f() # runs () -> console.log @bar
f.baz() # 'baz'
```

Notice that this solution does not return a callable object which inherits from `Foo.prototype` ([which is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340383/can-a-javascript-object-have-a-prototype-chain-but-also-be-a-function)), but that it does return a `Function` object in which some properties are mixed in.

A better pattern would be not to return a callable function object, but to return a standard object instance that has a `call` or `execute` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an variation on `Bergi's` answer:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@bar) ->
    foo = () =>
      console.log @bar
    foo.baz = ->
      console.log 'baz'
    return foo
f = new Foo 'bar'
f()
f.baz()
```

This may just be using `class` as a wrapper, much as `do()` does.  `f` is `{ [Function] baz: [Function] }`.  Also `Foo 'bar'` (without the `new`), produces the same thing.